# return type ‘SDL_Renderer {aka struct SDL_Renderer}’ is incomplete

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I'm using SDL2. I want to be able to access private member `_renderer` with a member function.

Here's the relevant code:

`Graphics.h`

```
#ifndef GRAPHICS_H
#define GRAPHICS_H

class Graphics {
public:
    Graphics();
    ~Graphics();
    SDL_Renderer    getRenderer();
private:
    SDL_Renderer    *_renderer;


#endif
```

`Graphics.cpp`

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include "Graphics.h"

SDL_Renderer Graphics::getRenderer(){
    return _renderer;
}
```

When I build, my compiler gives me this error:

```
../source/src/Graphics.cpp: In member function ‘SDL_Renderer Graphics::getRenderer()’:
../source/src/Graphics.cpp:49:36: error: return type ‘SDL_Renderer {aka struct SDL_Renderer}’ is incomplete
 SDL_Renderer Graphics::getRenderer(){
                                    ^
make: *** [source/src/Graphics.o] Error 1
source/src/subdir.mk:27: recipe for target 'source/src/Graphics.o' failed
```

How can I fix this so `getRenderer()` returns the renderer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SDL header file does not provide a definition of `SDL_Renderer`. It is an opaque type and should only be passed around by pointer or reference. Change your function's return type to `SDL_Renderer*`.

```
SDL_Renderer* Graphics::getRenderer(){
    return _renderer;
}
```

Comment: It worked! Can you tell me what you mean by "opaque type?" I am new to C++ and SDL2, so I want to make sure to understand things early to avoid picking up bad habits.

Comment: @Username: An opaque type is one which you cannot access directly, because its definition is not available to you. Notice you never access any members of an `SDL_Renderer` object (i.e. `_renderer->some_member`), you only ever pass it to functions by pointer. There's a wiki entry on it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type